# C++ SDL/SFML advancing help

Tags: c++, sdl, sfml

I've been playing around programming using SDL and SFML for a while now and done all the basic tutorials I can find(love lazyfoo).

but I'm stuck and not sure how to move on from simple games like Pong.

Could someone help point me in the right direction, I have a good understanding of the code I've worked with however not entirely sure how to apply it to more adventurous projects.

Is there a good game design theory site someone could recommended?

Any help or direction is really appreciated, let me know how you learnt and progressed :)

Comment: Whats stopping you from making more complex games? Pong has all the basics, like collision detection, key input, drawing sprites on the screen. If you know all of that you wont have much trouble making a slightly more complex games

Comment: Where to get started and what to learn next are not questions that are a good fit for the Q/A format of the site. See the [FAQ] about what types of questions to ask here and not ask. Also there's a few sites listed in the [FAQ] that will help you if you need a discussion.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to learn how to make more complex games is to start making more complex games. Just make games and on that path you'll meet with new problems which you'll solve at that time. Theory is nothing without practice - you'll easily forget it without applying it.

Once again, just **make games**! If you need ideas, I suggest you to take a look at this list:

[“I Need Practice Programming”: 49 Ideas for Game Clones to Code](http://inventwithpython.com/blog/2012/02/20/i-need-practice-programming-49-ideas-for-game-clones-to-code/)

Pick one game and start working on it. After each game you'll have more experience until you'll be experienced enough to make what you wish.

---

I started with Pong -> Tetris -> Sokoban -> My own ideas -> My current game

Comment: I want to add the best way to learn what you will need to know is to come across a problem you are unsure of how to solve. Try stuff, if it fails try something else. It may feel a bit hacky but many of your first games will be hacky. Do what you know and Google what you don't! That's what got me through school :D